# How could I simply compile GLSL to SPIR-V?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, spir-v

So I need to get the SPIR-V code of some GLSL

Every resource I can find on the topic involves setting up a whole enviroment for graphics and more.

In the simplest case when I have some GLSL code and I want to get the SPIR-V code, what would be the best way?

Comment: Does this help you ? https://community.khronos.org/t/compile-glsl-to-spir-v/7060/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Khronos group provide the Vulkan SDK, which is free to download. In that there is a command line tool `glslc` which you can call from the command line as so:

`VulkanSDK/x.x.x.x/Bin/glslc shader.vert -o vert.spv`

An example on how to use it also available in the [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Shader_modules#page_Compiling-the-shaders). It's pretty plug and play, just download the SDK and run from a terminal.

Comment: That seems great lead, thank you. Got little bit or work to check it's worked, but then I will mark this is the answer.